# Adding ICONS to CPT in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have this function, it is supposed to handle icons for CPT in wordpress , but Somehow it is not working ..

```
   add_action('admin_head', 'fbdf_cpt_icons_add');
    function fbdf_cpt_icons_add() {

        ?>
        <style>
        <?php if (($_GET['post_type'] == 'my_cpt') || ($post_type == 'my_cpt')) : ?>
        #icon-edit { background:transparent url('<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'/img/cpt.32.png';?>') no-repeat; }    
        <?php endif; ?>
            </style>
            <?php }
```

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, I have an idea..

you need to make `$post type` global..

Add   `global $post_type;` to the beginning of your function like so ..

```
add_action('admin_head', 'fbdf_cpt_icons_add');
    function fbdf_cpt_icons_add() {
      global $post_type; // here
        ?>
        <style>
        <?php if (($_GET['post_type'] == 'my_cpt') || ($post_type == 'my_cpt')) : ?>
        #icon-edit { background:transparent url('<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'/img/cpt.32.png';?>') no-repeat; }    
        <?php endif; ?>
            </style>
            <?php }
```

Comment: wow, thanks. it works now . ( but I can not still accept ) . DO You know how to change the title placeholder as well ?

Comment: I am glad it worked .. and that is a new question that is out of the scope of the original one. maybe you can open a new question if you do not find the answer yourself.